# Does su always change ruid, euid and suid to the same user id?

Tags: su, setuid

Does `su` always change ruid, euid and suid to the same user id, or just some of them?

I feel all of them, because the process which is executing `su` is always run with superuser privileges, and in which case, `setuid()` sets all three kinds of user ids to the same value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: as you say, `su` runs with superuser privileges, so [`setuid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setuid.html) sets all three user ids.

As explained in the rationale in [the POSIX spec for `setuid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setuid.html), this behaviour is necessary: otherwise the process started by `su` would be able to `setuid` back to the original user, which is *not* desirable.